# performance of business functions

Tags: performance

We have been using civi live for a few months in a hosted environment. In response to concerns from the admin team I took some timings for common tasks and agree with them that performance is very disappointing. We intend to use a monitoring package to investigate but would be grateful for any views on the results below:

- search for a contact = 8 secs
- select edit a contact = 5 sec
- edit a contact field <1 sec
- save edited contact = 8 sec
- edit a financial type = 5 sec
- edit a communication preference = 7 sec
- renew a membership = 3 secs
- edit greeting = 6 secs
- edit address = 8 secs

The system is accessed over broadband and other services are fine.

I realise there are many hardware, software, database issues that can affect performance but would be grateful for any comments on the general premise from administrators that they system is very slow.

Thankyou

Comment: Can you add some information about your hosted environment

Comment: Since it's hosted, talk to your hosting provider.  Sometimes their performance monitoring can provide useful clues.  Is your CMS slow as well or just Civi?

Comment: You could compare with the development sandboxes, which run on a virtual server with 4 GB ram: https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

The number of contacts & contributions will slow down searches. If using Drupal, make sure that the Watchdog is not clogged with warnings. The watchdog often kills performance.

Comment: Thank you all. I have managed to view civi on a modest hosting environment giving much better performance so I think it is time to move to another hosting.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do not have access to that information but have requested it from the relevant person.